# WordPress First Recent Post

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress I want to get the most recent posts, however I want to display the first most recent post bigger in a different div. How do I seperate the first most recent post?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://goo.gl/d0AbHn

You could modify the css to use the `first-child` selector:

```
[POST-CLASS]:first-child {
    font-size: 30px;
    [...]
}
```

Or, install the 'display posts shortcode' plugin and use the schortcode [display-posts posts_per_page="1"]

Comment: Thanks, but I want to put the first post in a different div to the rest

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Ok, but I still want to have numerous posts on that page, just the most recent one bigger

Comment: That's why you should use this plugin/shortcode:  `<div>[display-posts posts_per_page="1"]</div> <div>[display-posts posts_per_page="10"]</div> `